# Include Microsoft team meetings while setting meeting in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

Does anyone know how to include Team Meetings while setting meeting in Outlook using the VBA code below?

[image: Teams meeting in outlook]

Below is my code:

```
Sub setmeeting()

    Dim O As Outlook.Application
    Dim OAPT As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    Set O = New Outlook.Application

    Set OAPT = O.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    OAPT.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

    With OAPT

        .RequiredAttendees = "abc@gmail.com"
        .OptionalAttendees = "abc@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "I Love VBA"
        .Start = "11/21/2019 12:00:00 PM"
        .End = "11/21/2019 12:30:00 PM"
        .Body = "Hello World"
        .Location = "Cubicle"
        .Display
        .Send

    End With

    Set OAPT = Nothing
    Set O = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub teammetting()


Dim nm As Outlook.AppointmentItem


Set nm = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

nm.MeetingStatus = olMeeting



nm.Subject = "Subject"



nm.Start = 'format:DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM



nm.End =""'format:DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM


nm.requiredattendees "mail address of the invitees"


nm.Body = "Set the body of the email"



nm.Display

SendKeys "{F10}", True


SendKeys "H", True


SendKeys "TM", True



end sub
```

if you are doing a loop add wait time before the start of next loop